# Is there any way to convert csv data to array of values

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have added jsfiddel link. What I tried so far. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks you

```js
function onFileSelect(input) {
  //this.itemHeaderName = itemHeaderName;
  var files = input.files;
  var csvData;
  if (files && files.length) {
    var fileToRead = files[0];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToRead, 'UTF-8');
    fileReader.onloadend = function(x) {
      csvData = fileReader.result;
      onFileLoad(csvData);
    }

  }
}

function onFileLoad(fileLoadedEvent) {
  var csvSeparator = ',';
  var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent;
  var csv = [];
  var rows = textFromFileLoaded.split('\n');

  _.forEach(rows, function(element) {
    var col = [];
    col = element.split(csvSeparator);
    csv.push(col);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>

<input id="uploadFile_hier" type="file" class="upload" onclick="onFileSelect(event.target)" multiple="false" />
```

CSV file data:

```
Part    Property    Level   Comments
Mercury Sub 2   TOP,Bottom,5678
copper  Material    1   KM
Iron    Thickness   4   NA,KA
```

Result :

```
\["part", "Property", "Level", "Comments"\]
\["Mercury", "Sub-Compound", "2", ""TOP", "NOZZLE", "BLOCK", "9100""\]
\["copper", "Material", "1", "KM"\]
\["Iron", "Thickness", "4", ""NA", "KA""\]
```

Expected:

```
\["part", "Property", "Level", "Comments"\]
\["Mercury", "Sub-Compound", "2", "TOP,NOZZLE,BLOCK,9100"\]
\["copper", "Material", "1", "KM"\]
\["Iron", "Thickness", "4", "NA,KA"\]][1]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eswar786/t5mpojr2/

Comment: geez, that CSV data doesn't have many commas

Comment: Can you explain what you want?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eswar786/t5mpojr2/

Comment: where did `"Sub-Compound", "2", ""TOP", "NOZZLE", "BLOCK", "9100"` come from ... not the data that's for sure

Comment: the problem with csv's is, you can have `"data,with,comma"` that should be treated like a single value, because it's got quotes around it ... so you'll need to programatically deal with such cases. Then there's the case where you may want quotes in the value, so you need to deal with that too ... and what if the data has `"`, `'` AND `,` in it ... that's a complex field that is always possible in a CSV, so, you need to parse that too ... it's a very complex thing to parse CSV correctly - just thinking about it makes me stutter ... papaparse (dot com)

Comment: ignore the output values but the format of structure I need. you can give any data instead of these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rows.forEach(element => {
if (element.indexOf('"') >= 0) {
const str = element.slice(element.indexOf('"'), element.length);
const str1 = element.slice(0,element.indexOf('"'));
element = str1 + str.replace(/[',]+/g, '-');
}
```

inside loop take each value from the array and find out the wherever double quotes are occurring then replace that one with  -